# RPython copy string with quotes from R to Python

Tags: python, r, string, rpython

I have trouble copying a string from R to a string in Python using RPython. I know the basic steps of doing it if the string does not have quotes but it gives error if the string has quotes.

For example:

```
test <- "byte"
python.assign("string",test)
python.exec("print(string)")
```

Works fine and prints:  byte

However,

```
test <- "'byte'"
python.assign("string",test)
```

gives error:

```
File "<string>", line 2
    string =' [ "'byte'" ] '
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If i try to escape quote characters:

```
test <- "\'byte\'"
python.assign("string",test)
```

same error:

```
File "<string>", line 2
    string =' [ "'byte'" ] '
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Or if I change internal single quotes to double quotes:

```
test <- "\"byte\""
python.assign("string",test)
Error in python.exec(python.command) : 
  Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 6 (char 5)
```

Any ideas what am I missing, or some direction where to look ?

Thank you

Comment: I've never used RPython, but have you tried "\\'byte\\'" ? (this would tell python that the quote is present, I guess)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately I still get error as in the last example:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I managed to copy the string {"byte"} (i.e. string with double quotes) using matiasg advice. So if I say: test <- '\\"byte\\"' then RPython will accept it. However, this does not solve my question as it still fails if I want to copy a string with single quotes, i.e. it fails if I say test <- "\\'byte\\'" and then try to do python.assign("string", test). I think we are getting there though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also searching for good answer for this question.
I can suggest workaround only:

**Your** example:

```
library('rPython')
python.exec("string=chr(39).join(['byte'])")
python.get("string")
[1] "byte"
# Alternatively: python.exec("string=chr(39) + \"byte\" + chr(39)")
# to get: [1] "'byte'"
```

Something more complex: Suppose 'I want' "something" like 'this'

```
library('rPython')
python.exec("string=\"Suppose \" + chr(39) + \"I want\" + chr(39) + \" \" + chr(34) + \"something\" + chr(34) + \" like \" + chr(39) + \"this\" + chr(39)")
python.get("string")
[1] "Suppose 'I want' \"something\" like 'this'"
```

Another example:

```
library('rPython')
python.exec("myCommand=\"gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Int16 -a_nodata \" + chr(39) +\"-32768\" + chr(39) + \" NETCDF:\" + chr(39) + \"inputFile\" + chr(39) + \":Soil_Moisture \" + chr(39) + \"outputFile\" + chr(39)")
python.get("myCommand")
[1] "gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Int16 -a_nodata '-32768' NETCDF:'inputFile':Soil_Moisture 'outputFile'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from @matandked, you could replace single quotes with `chr(39)` using `gsub`:

```
library(rPython)

test <- "'byte'"

python.assign("string", gsub("\\'", "' + chr(39) + '", test))
python.get("string")

# [1] "'byte'"
```

There may be unintended consequences, but `python.assign` could be modified in a similar fashion:

```
python.assign <- function (var.name, value, ...) 
{
  value <- gsub("\\'", "' + chr(39) + '", value) ## Added this line...
  value <- toJSON(value, collapse = "", ...)
  python.command <- c(paste(var.name, "='", value, "'", sep = " "), 
                      paste(var.name, "= json.loads(", var.name, ")", sep = ""), 
                      paste("if len(", var.name, ") == 1:", sep = ""), paste("    ", 
                                                                             var.name, "=", var.name, "[0]"))
  python.command <- paste(python.command, collapse = "\n")
  python.exec(python.command)
  invisible(NULL)
}


## Now there's no need to substitute single quotes:
python.assign("string", test)
python.get("string")

# [1] "'byte'"
```