# How to escape quotes when calling Python from R using rPython package

Tags: python, r, escaping

I'm trying to execute the following commands using rPython, from R. The individual lines work fine in Python, when the variables are defined appropriately. I've come as far to realize that it's probably an issue with escaping the double quote, but I'm not clear on how to fix it.

```
fname <- "some string"
rPython::python.assign("fstr", fname)
rPython::python.exec("print(fstr)")
```

This prints correctly in the R console, so it's not an issue getting Python to know the value of `fstr`.

```
rPython::python.exec("f = open(fstr+'_d.txt','r')") 

# some lines in f contain the word "leaf" and also contain a character string in double quotes; if "leaf" is on a given line, I would like to extract that character string to a list
rPython::python.exec('matched_lines = [line.split("\"")[1] for line in f.readlines() if \"leaf\" in line]') 
rPython::python.exec("f.close()")

rPython::python.exec("print(matched_lines)") # returns the expected output


# and then I'd like to write it to a file.
rPython::python.exec("f = open(fstr+'_d_char.txt','wb')") 
rPython::python.exec("f.write('\n'.join(matched_lines))")
```

Here's the error:

```
File "<string>", line 2
    f.write('
            ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I've been trying to escape this quote in various ways, mimicking my earlier issue with "leaf," but with little success.

I could find a way to do the same operations in R I think, but I'm curious why this, in particular, isn't working.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884625/rpython-copy-string-with-quotes-from-r-to-python) helped me solve the earlier issue but using `rPython::python.exec("f.write(\\'\n\\'.join(matched_lines))")` just gives me "SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character."

Comment: Incidentally, I'm not sure what to do about this, but the [tag:rpython] tag is referring to something else entirely. I'm not sure if I should be using a tag to refer to rPython (the package) - other questions are marked with [tag:rpython], even though this is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple issues. The issue was not only about escaping the quotes, but also about my failure to escape the newline. The correct code to use is

```
rPython::python.exec("f.write(\'\\n\'.join(matched_lines))")
```